# php - mime type/extension

Tags: php, types, mime

Hi how do i allow only word documents? And i mean both mime-type and extension? Right now i have these codes checking extensions for .txt files, how do i change it to accept only word docs.

```
if ($uploaded_type !=="text/plain")
```

and

```
if($ext !== 'txt')
```

Comment: Just a note - you can't trust the supplied mime type or extension. Be sure to do some sort of validation on it if the type really matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS Word documents are `application/msword` or `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` mime types and `doc` or `docx` extensions.

Answer (score 1):

`application/msword` for `.doc` and `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` for `.docx`.

See http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php

Answer (score -1):

I belive https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php is what you are looking for

Comment: Squadroo wanted the actual MIME type to check if the MIME type he gets (with that or a similar function) is correct.